# Correctly saved timezone aware datetime object appearing timezone unaware when accessed in Django app

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

In a Django app w/ postgresql backend I maintain, users log in and post comments. Every comment has a timestamp associated to it.

When creating the comment object, I do:

```
now = datetime.now()
Comment.objects.create(commenter=self.request.user, when=now, text='text')
```

`now` is timezone aware - i.e. I am UTC +530, and `now` encodes that information correctly. If I use `psql` and peek at the entry created in the Comment postgresql table, I see the correct value for the datetime object.

However, if I access this same object from the Django app, and `print` out its datetime stamp, I see a timezone **unaware** object. I.e. a datetime object that doesn't know I'm at UTC +530.

This is totally messing up my logic. How do I ensure I get the same datetime object in the Django app that's saved in its related postgresql table? It's remarkable that the two outputs are different, I'm probably doing something fundamentally wrong. Help!

Comment: datetime.now() is never timezone aware, unlike datetime.utcnow()

Comment: @Apero: then is it a quirk of postgresql that I'm seeing a timezone aware value in the table via `psql`? What do you think is going on here? I'm trying to make sense of it.

Comment: I believe postgres indeed stores it in its own timezone. the django setting USE_TZ, as mentioned by @Elwin Arens will take the time into the datetime object when deserializing it fron postgres to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [timezone.now()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) instead of datetime.now():

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.now()
```

To get now() either with or without timezone globally for the whole app (including PostgreSQL schema updates). With or without time zone depends on the [USE_TZ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) setting.

Comment: use `timezone.now()` and `USE_TZ=True`, to avoid ambiguous times.